# How to pass a state variable between components

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass down the 'year' state variable to the Playlist class; so far when the user presses enter after filling in an input, the input is saved in Class Home's state variable 'year', but I need it passed down to the Playlist class, and what I've found online isn't suiting it as far as I'm seeing/trying.

```
class App extends Component {   
  render() {    
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Route exact path = '/' component= {Home}/>
          <Route path= '/playlist' component = {Playlist}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    ); 
  }
}
export default App;

class Home extends Component {
      constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            year: ' '
         };
         this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
         this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
      }

      updateInput(event){
         this.setState({year : event.target.value})
      }

      handleSubmit(event){
         alert("Year Submitted");
         this.props.history.push('/playlist');
         event.preventDefault();
      }
  render() {    
     return (
        <div id="body" className="Home">
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                 <input id = "yearInput" autoComplete="off" type="text" placeholder = 
                "Enter Year" onChange={this.updateInput} />
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
  }
}
export default Home;

class Playlist extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         year: ' '
       };
        this.goingBack = this.goingBack.bind(this);
    }

    goingBack(){
        console.log(this.year);
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="Playlist">
                <h1> Playlist </h1>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.goingBack}> Go back </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Playlist;
```

Comment: If `Home` and `Playlist` are sibling components, you can [**lift up the state**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).  Alternatively, you can employ [**Context**](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [**Redux**](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) to solve this issue.

Comment: What component is rendering Playlist? My assumption is Home is the parent component so you would just pass year down as props.

Comment: Playlist is being rendered on handleSubmit(event) on the input tag. So Home is the parent component, and yes I'm trying to pass year down as props but am not sure how @DannyMoshe

Comment: So there is a router which renders Home and Playlist? When you render the Home component, you pass down a function to set state on the router. Then in the router when you render the playlist component you grab state from the state of the router. Just a guess since I cant see all of your code.

Comment: Showing where Home and Playlist components are actually rendered would be helpful. Home is not rendering Playlist just making a request at the /Playlist route..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in route state. Assuming both are being directly rendered by a `Route` component, then both have access to [route-props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props).

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      year: ' '
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
  }

  updateInput(event) {
    this.setState({ year: event.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("Year Submitted");
    this.props.history.push({ // <-- use object form of push
      pathname: '/playlist',
      state: { year: this.state.year },
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="body" className="Home">
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input id="yearInput" autoComplete="off" type="text" placeholder=
              "Enter Year" onChange={this.updateInput} />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can access route state via `this.props.location.state`

```
class Playlist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // If user navigates directly to "/playlist" state object
      // is undefined, so use a guard to protect against "access
      // ... of undefined..." errors. Also provide a default/fallback
      // value, i.e. the empty string ''.
      year: (props.location.state && props.location.state.year) || '';
    };
    this.goingBack = this.goingBack.bind(this);
  }

  goingBack() {
    console.log(this.state.year); // <--- Update to this.state.year!!
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Playlist">
        <h1> Playlist </h1>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.goingBack}> Go back </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Playlist;
```

[image: Edit simple route state]

Comment: I tried the changes you made, although it makes sense, the console.log(this.props.year) in the goingBack() function from the Playlist class, doesn't log the input I entered in the input tag from Class Home

Comment: @surpol There was a copy/paste bug in `goingBack`, should be `this.state.year`. I caught it when making a codesandbox demo to add to asnwer. It's updated now.